# OAuth serverless provider

Tags: oauth, serverless, oauth.io

I'm looking for OAuth serverless provider with:

1. OAuth authentication for major providers
2. Access to the providers' API

I already spent some time playing with OAuth.io service and was able to build prototype based on NodeJS. I successfully implemented authentication with Facebook, Twitter, Github, Stackexchange, Google, Linkedin. Integration with Paypal failed.

That is what I found for OAuth.io:

Proc:

1. List of supported providers
2. User-friendly management console
3. Authentication flow, simple integration

Cons:

1. Access to Github, Linkedin API generates an errors due to changes in their APIs. Looks like these changes were not reflected in OAuth SDKs.
2. Low activity at Github. Last commit for NodeJS SDK was made in Nov 2016.

Is there any other OAuth serverless providers on the market?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Another oauth.io user here. I like the simplicity of their SDK, but their dashboard doesn't work at the moment (only loading spinners).

A great alternative is https://auth0.com, lots of features and integrations. You also have access to the provider's API, like you asked. You can find an example of using Auth0 to access the GitHub API here: https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/github

Since you mentioned serverless, auth0.com also have a very nice serverless platform https://webtask.io where you can run your own NodeJS functions in the cloud. I found it a much more intuitive/enjoyable experience than AWS Lambda, and it integrates directly with auth0.com.

Downsides of Auth0 are the steeper learning curve compared to oauth.io (they started off very simple, but now it seems they want to be the be all end all of auth) and less customisation of the login screen/flow. Basically they want you to redirect your users to a login screen that they host and designed.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for auth0, I will check this solution.